# Make spreadsheet cell A1 active

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm using openpyxl to put a bunch of data into an existing Excel workbook, but I would like to make sure that when someone opens it that cell A1 is the active cell (and scrolled into view).

Comment: It's possible but you'll have to dig around in the source code, I think.

Comment: If `openpyxl` doesn't make that functionality available, you can directly use COM automation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15467331/4996248 If you get stuck on some point regarding the Excel object model you could perhaps ask about it on either the `vbscript` or the `excel-vba` tag